# AdMob Ionic 2 NO AD

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I have seen that this problem is common, but I can't find the solution to this:

```
2017-03-17 14:29:12.228434 foo[18824:3053919] AdMob, onAdFailLoad, {'adNetwork':'AdMob','adType':'banner','adEvent':'onAdFailLoad','error':1,'reason':'Request Error: No ad to show.'}
```

My code:

```
  loadAd(){

    let options = {};

    if(this.platform.is('android')){
      let options = {
        adId: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxxx',
        isTesting: false,
        adSize : AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER
      };
    }else{
      let options = {
        adId: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxxx',
        isTesting: false,
        adSize : AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER
      };
    }


    AdMob.createBanner(options).then(() => {
      AdMob.showBanner(8);
    });

  }
```

I also have `5 Mediation sources` set.
Did you guys found any solutions to this? My app isn't published yet on the AppStore

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that admob cannot provide a suitable ad for yourad-unit ID. 
Have you checked that the ad-unit id is correct?